# Is it possible to update rows in Azure Data Explorer (Kusto)

Tags: azure-data-explorer

1. Is it possible to update rows in Azure Data Explorer?
2. Is it a good choice for storing large inventory (100M items) that are updated frequently or it is mostly optimized to append-only data scenarios? My repository is updated around the clock and I need the changes visible immediately (near-real-time).
3. Assuming I need full-text search, faceting, and basic items queries/lookups and near real-time updates (which flows in around the clock). how does it compare to ElasticSearch? Assuming I consume both as managed service. I'm mostly concerned about the updates part.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Updating single records isn't possible. You do have the option to update data in batches, by [tagging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/extents-overview#extent-tagging) it at ingestion time, and using shard-level commands (such as [.replace extents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/extents-commands#replace-extents)) when you need to perform the 'update'.
2. While it's perhaps not the "natural" choice, you could still theoretically achieve that, by ingesting a new record for each update, and using [arg_max()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/arg-max-aggfunction) to always get the latest version per item.

   - There's an upcoming feature, Materialized Views, which can (until it's available, you can orchestrate that materialization periodically using any scheduler that [ingests from a query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-from-query))
3. A full and meaningful comparison isn't a one-liner (there are too many considerations to list), and in most cases - the result of such comparison would be very specific to your use case, budget, personal preference, performance requirements, etc. That said, all of the features you listed are supported by ADX/Kusto.

Comment: Thanks Yoni! I've added some more details to the question. From your answer, it sounds a bit more like a workaround than normal product usage? Are these solutions viable in situations where a constant flow of updates (more than inserts) flows in and need immidiate (less than second) visability?

Comment: ADX/Kusto, as an append-only store, is not necessarily your optimal choice for very frequently updated data. that said, the techniques i mentioned are used widely at different scales by customers who have preferred to have that part of their data in ADX/Kusto alongside other less-frequently (or not-at-all) updated data sets, for example - due to considerations of convenience (e.g. having all data in a single service, using the same query language, etc). if your main and only use case entails very frequent updates, i'm not sure either the technologies you mentioned are the most suitable ones.

Answer (score 4):

If we're talking about a small table, you can update records in Kusto using this technique:

```
.ingest inline into table temp_ABC <|
01,John,Doe,21
02,Jim,Brown,23

.set-or-replace ABC <| temp_ABC

.drop table temp_ABC
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see the new "[.update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/update-table-command)" command (currently in preview state) and see the section regarding choosing materialized views or update command for data updates in Azure Data Explorer.

Comment: On Feb 20 2024 the azure data explorer team introduced the .update command. This command allows you to update records by deleting existing records and appending new ones in a single transaction.

Azure data explorer doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/update-table-command

Release Announcement from Azure Data Explorer Blog https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-explorer-blog/update-records-in-a-kusto-database-public-preview/bc-p/4063480